# Why is my custom comparator only making a single comparison?

Tags: list, sorting, groovy, comparator

I'm trying to use a custom comparator to sort a list of two or more known strings. I want the list to contain only the strings before and after the sort operation, so I used an enum to define the correct order. The below works as expected in an online console:

```
    ​class StringComparator implements Comparator<String> {
        enum validStrings {
        string_should_be_first,
        string_second,
        string3,
        string_four,
        string_five
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
            if (validStrings[str1].ordinal() == validStrings[str2].ordinal()){
                return 0
            }
            else{
                println("Comparing ${validStrings[str1].ordinal()} and ${validStrings[str2].ordinal()}")
                return (validStrings[str2].ordinal() < validStrings[str1].ordinal()) ? 1 : -1;
            }
       }
   }

    mylist = ["string_second", "string_five", "string3", "string_should_be_first"]​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
    println(mylist)
    Collections.sort(mylist, new StringComparator())
    println(mylist)​
```

Outputs (Correct, and prints many "comparing" statements as expected:

```
    [string_second, string_five, string3, string_should_be_first]
    Comparing 1 and 4
    Comparing 4 and 2
    Comparing 1 and 2
    Comparing 4 and 0
    Comparing 2 and 0
    Comparing 1 and 0
    [string_should_be_first, string_second, string3, string_five]
```

When I try to move it to an IDE, however(Visual Studio Code), my custom comparator stops working. I specifically notice that it only makes a single comparison before leaving the original list unchanged:

StringComparator.groovy

```
    ​class StringComparator implements Comparator<String> {
        enum validStrings {
        string_should_be_first,
        string_second,
        string3,
        string_four,
        string_five
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
            if (validStrings[str1].ordinal() == validStrings[str2].ordinal()){
                return 0
            }
            else{
                println("Comparing ${validStrings[str1].ordinal()} and ${validStrings[str2].ordinal()}")
                return (validStrings[str2].ordinal() < validStrings[str1].ordinal()) ? 1 : -1;
            }
        }
    }
```

OtherClass.groovy

```
    import *.StringComparator
    ....
    mylist = ["string_four", "string_should_be_first", "string3", "string_second"]
    println("Initial: ${mylist}")
    Collections.sort(mylist)
    println("Default sort: ${mylist}")
    Collections.sort(mylist, new StringComparator())
    println("Custom sort: ${mylist}")
```

Outputs:

```
    Initial: [string_four, string_should_be_first, string3, string_second]
    Default sort: [string3, string_four, string_second, string_should_be_first]
    Comparing 2 and 4
    Custom sort: [string3, string_four, string_second, string_should_be_first]
```

I can't figure out why my custom comparator works in the online console, but not in the IDE, or why it's only attempting one comparison, and then leaving the list unchanged -- I would greatly appreciate any help or guidance.

Comment: `Collection.sort` ? should be `Collections.sort`... and you are printing only in one of if-else case in comparator.

Comment: Yes, sorry that was a copy/paste typo. I am using Collections consistently -- I've updated it in my question. In both the online console and visual studio code, I only added the debug message in one place (when 1 or -1 is returned by comparator). With the online console, however, it produces 6 comparisons and print messages.

Please let me know if my question/intention is not clear.

Comment: then possibly the problem in your IDE...